# How can I print a length of hsize (Horizontal size) in mm (millimeter)?

Tags: lengths

I am new to VTEX. How can i solve this??

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\the\hsize
\end{document}
```

Output: 345.0 pt

but i have to write a macro to calculate hsize in mm
example: `\printdimen[mm]\hsize` 
and if i take hsize 6.5in then what will be output in mm?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22701/is-there-a-command-to-convert-cm-to-bp and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8260/what-are-the-various-units-ex-em-in-pt-bp-dd-pc-expressed-in-mm/8337#8337

Comment: You already received an answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239660/8528

Comment: You've already asked two questions in this area, and have answers on the previous one that cover this (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239647/how-can-i-print-a-length-in-centimeters-in-vtex). Closure as a dupe of your existing question is likely unless you can make a case for this one being distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\getlength}[3]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro#1{#3*#2}
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\printdimen { o m }{%
    \getlength{\tmp}{\convertto{#1}{1pt}}{#2}\SI{\tmp}{#1}
}


\begin{document}  
\begin{align*}  
    \text{\the\hsize} &\equiv \printdimen[mm]\hsize \\
                      &\equiv \printdimen[cm]\hsize \\
                      &\equiv \printdimen[ex]\hsize \\                    
                      &\equiv \printdimen[em]\hsize \\      
                      &\equiv \printdimen[bp]\hsize \\
                      &\equiv \printdimen[dd]\hsize \\                    
                      &\equiv \printdimen[pc]\hsize \\  
                      &\equiv \printdimen[in]\hsize                                    
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For VTeX...........?

Comment: @jon no idea, what that is. Sorry.

Comment: No e-TeX extensions.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi  i want to show output only 121.25221 mm. In that case what i have to do? whenever i use \printdimen[mm]\hsize then output ll be only 21.25221 mm  "Thanks"

Comment: @enadulshaheen you get 21... when compiling my MWE?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi sorry it should be 121.25221 mm (not 21.25221). I mean when i will write \printdimen[mm]\hsize  then output will be only 121.25221 mm. Thats all. "Thanks"

Comment: @enadulshaheen sorry, I don't get it. The output of my macro is exactly what you desire.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{printlen}
\begin{document}
\uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\hsize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: like that \printdimen[mm]\hsize